UI5 Routing - Route to different object target depending on button pressed
I have the following code in my Master.controller:
if (sTab === "headers") {
    this.getRouter().navTo("objectHeader", {
        Posid : oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("Posid")
    }, bReplace);
} else {
    this.getRouter().navTo("object", {
        Posid : oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("Posid")
    }, bReplace);
}

I assumed this would mean that this would route to a different object page depending on the result of the variable "sTab", but it doesn't.  It just routes to "object" always and never seems to hit "objectHeader".
Manifest:
"routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.f.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewPath": "[redacted].view",
                "controlId": "layout",
                "controlAggregation": "beginColumnPages",
                "bypassed": {
                    "target": "notFound"
                },
                "async": true
            },
            "routes": [
                {
                    "pattern": "",
                    "name": "master",
                    "target": "master"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "JobSet/{Posid}",
                    "name": "object",
                    "target": [
                        "master",
                        "object"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "JobSet/{Posid}",
                    "name": "objectHeader",
                    "target": [
                        "master",
                        "objectHeader"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "targets": {
                "master": {
                    "viewName": "Master",
                    "viewLevel": 1,
                    "viewId": "master"
                },
                "object": {
                    "viewName": "Detail",
                    "viewId": "detail",
                    "viewLevel": 1,
                    "controlAggregation": "midColumnPages"
                },
                "objectHeader": {
                    "viewName": "DetailHeader",
                    "viewId": "detailHeader",
                    "viewLevel": 1,
                    "controlAggregation": "midColumnPages"
                },
                "detailObjectNotFound": {
                    "viewName": "DetailObjectNotFound",
                    "viewId": "detailObjectNotFound",
                    "controlAggregation": "midColumnPages"
                },
                "notFound": {
                    "viewName": "NotFound",
                    "viewId": "notFound"
                }
            }
        }

Can anyone help me with this? If sTab === "headers" then it should route to DetailHeader.view and not Detail.view

You have the same pattern "JobSet/{Posid}" in both routes mentioned. Change a pattern for one of them, that should help with the issue.

But they are the same entityset, with the same pattern.  We are reading PS WBS elements, soem are level 3 and some are level 4, if the user clicks on a level 3 WBS then it will show a different Detail page to the level 4 WBS.  I'm not sure how we can give it a different pattern without large changes to the service.

Do you subscribe to PatternMatched of sap.ui.core.routing.Route class in the controllers of these views? If so, try to detach the event handler before performing a navigation to another target with the same pattern. I guest that currently you have 2 event handlers for the same pattern and it seems that only the first of them is called

The router class evaluates the routes array in sequence every time the hash is changed in the app. So @shahhmatist is correct. You should not have 2 routes with the same pattern or an equivalent one. That is why you should have more specific routes first and more generic ones at the end. Also you should consider route parameters on this equation. If you have pattern :anything: as your first route, no other route will be called as anything between :: is considered as an optional argument and any hash would match that pattern.
